# structure of posts and pages

Tags: posts, pages, urls

I have wordpress website which had some static pages and posts.
I want to show pages URL as below:

```
mywebsite.com/PageName1
mywebsite.com/PageName2
...
```

also I have some posts that will be more in next, and my desired structure for post url is:

```
mywebsite.com/blog/PostName1 
mywebsite.com/blog/PostName2
...
```

I should say that I make a category with name "Blog" and all of my website posts are in this category.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the answer, i set it in parmalink section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure that in admin panel. Just go »Dashboard > Settings > Permalink« settings.

Comment: Would like to leave comments, but I need 50 reputatuion, and how does this not provide an answer, isn't this the way you may do what he asked?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide more details and how answer addresses the specific question. _A lot_ of things can be changed in settings, that's why they are called settings. :) _How_ should settings be used to possibly achieve the specifics of the question?